# 'Jekyll Serve' Error

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to run my jekyll site locally but when executing the command:

```
jekyll serve
```

I receive the following error message:

```
bhavik-imac:dhokes.github.io bhavikdhokia$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/bhavikdhokia/Development/git/dhokes.github.io/_config.yml
/Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-sitemap (LoadError)
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:29:in `block in require_gems'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `each'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `require_gems'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:79:in `setup'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `initialize'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `new'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/bhavikdhokia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions as to why this is and how to resolve this?

Comment: So, have you installed `jekyll-sitemap`? Try `gem install jekyll-sitemap` and repeat.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Thanks. If you submit that as an answer, I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have to install `jekyll-sitemap` Try to install it by `gem install jekyll-sitemap`.

Answer (score 1):

For people Googling this problem, also try `bundle update` if you're using bundle.